# FilePicker alternative for Blackberry OS pre-5.0

Tags: blackberry

[FilePicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/FilePicker.html) is supported from Blackberry OS 5.0 and above. Is there any alternate to this class in 4.5/4.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to code it yourself, but RIM provides a sample: [How To Create A File Selection Popup Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_To_-_Create_a_File_Selection_Popup_Screen.html?nodeid=1498743&vernum=0).